# Can the Limbo clones use all the techniques of the jutsu owner?

Tags: naruto

## Note: This question contains spoilers from the Manga! Anime viewers are advised  not to read it!

Madara uses invisible clones from [Limbo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Limbo:_Border_Jail). Can those clones use all of Madara's techniques themselves?

Comment: The following was taken from naruto wikia. 'This(limbo) can operate independently of the user and attack or restrain target(s), or defend the original body from attacks as the shadow was strong enough to **repel** all nine tailed beasts in a single instance '. The word **repel** alerts me that, the clone might have used [Shinra Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinra_Tensei).

Answer (score 1):

It is actually unclear. The Limbo clones can apparently fly and block physical attacks, and they also have the same Rinnegan as the original (they are, after all, clones).

But we haven't seen any evidence of the clones being able to use any sort of technique aside from basic taijutsu.

Since the manga is over and the databook doesn't provide any new data on this subject, the final answer would be **No**. Limbo clones cannot use ninjutsu by the original.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The clones have rinnegan and have same chakra as the owner (not the quantity here but the quality).

Each one if desires can activate a susano. It seems from the manga, sharingan techniques have been concluded to be weaker than what madara is using now.

Comment: Can you point out a chapter proving this? Just curious. Because they were mostly invisible and only visible through Sasuke's eyes.

Comment: I don't seem to recall Madara using a Susanoo after getting the Rinnegan let alone his limbo clones using it.

Answer (score 0):

Limbo clones can attack. there was a part where sasuke dealt with limbo and naruto had to deal with the original. Then naruto had to fight a limbo, he looked like an idiot to kakashi and sakura at that time. Finnaly he pinned one of the limbo. If I'm not wrong. could not recall which chapter but it does proves that a limbo can use all madara techniques.

Comment: Just because they fought, doesn't mean that they can use ninjutsu. We haven't seen a single jutsu used by any of the limbo clones.